# Rend highchart graph, wait for getJSON response PHP

Tags: php, json, highcharts, render

I'm querying data in a postgresql DB, and printing result in JSON format:

Server/PHP:

```
$result = array();
$result['name'] = 'serie1';
while($r = pg_fetch_array($query)) {
     $result['category'][] = $r['day'];
     $result['data'][] = $r['temperature']; 
}
$json = array();
array_push($json,$result);
print json_encode($json);
```

JSON outoput:

**[{"category":[1,2,3,4,5],"data":[25,30,33,13,16]}]**

Either My JSON output is not the right one for a simple highchart or the graph is rendered before the SQL result from PHP is ready!

Ho can I render the graph after JSON response is ready and how to set the format to highchart structure?

Client/HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'test',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'test'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }

            $.getJSON("test.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['category'];
                options.series[0] = {};
                //options.series[0].name = json[0]['name'];
                options.series[0].name = 'test';
                options.series[0].data = json[0]['data'];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            );
        });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Approach seems fine. What's in your console?

Comment: The graph does not show! It looks like SQL result is not even retrieved. Perhaps a callback or so is needed.

Comment: That's what you are doing already. What is in your Javascript console? Any errors?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Then you've got one `)` too many, ore you've inserted one where it isn't suppose to be.

Comment: sorry, this error was during my edit. Actually there is no error, it seems that JSON is not retrieved. My DB is in a remote server, code in another one. there are no error in the console, graph just does not plot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59883/discussion-between-algina-and-ondkloss).

Comment: Probrably you cave cors problem (domain conflict, please ensure that you use jsonp not json).